# Adding a new name and password to a list

Tags: python, password-encryption

How can I add a name and password to my list named, "samplePasswordFile" using Python 3.

I need to do this:

```
if(choice == '3'):
    print("What website is this password for?")
    website = input()
    print("What is the password?")
    unencryptedPassword = input()
```

Using this information:

```
encryptedPassword = passwordEncrypt(unencryptedPassword,encryptionKey)]
```

- the encryptionKey variable is defined already as 16, don't change this
- create a list of size 2, first item the website name and the second item the password.
- append the list from Step 2 to the password list

Comment: Try `samplePasswordFile.append([website, encryptedPassword])`

Comment: Martineau, no it doesn't work, it's telling me: NameError: name 'samplePasswordFile' is not defined?